# Do healers heal P.E.K.K.A.?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Suppose I train 4 Pekkas (high level) and put three healers on each, i.e. 4 Pekkas and 6 healers(high level) and fill the rest with barchers. Will the Pekkas survive long enough to destroy at least 50%, considering healers don't get killed by air defenses (suppose they get destroyed by hogs or lightning).

I have used 2/3 healers on archer queen again a 1500 trophy guy and queen was harmless till the end. So will healers work on Pekkas too in the same way?

Comment: Why wouldn't healers heal P.E.K.K.A.s?

Answer (score 1):

Healers can heal any ground unit but you have to consider many factors. Assuming you are th 9 so if you are attacking a max th 9 you have to use 4 healers each but it won't make the invincible you have to drop rage on healers when pekka health goes down. To be honest using healers on pekka would be really bad instead you could use healers on heroes, giants and bowlers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, healers can heal pekkas ([source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Healer)). They can heal any ground unit, however whether or not they can heal a pekka enough to keep them alive long enough to destroy 50% of a base depends on the base. It might work just fine for some weaker bases, but on stronger bases, there is a much lower chance of it working.